# What is the drawback in keep using design pattern used in this javascript code

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

```
var fs = require('fs');
var fileName = 'README.txt';
fs.exists(fileName, function(exists) {
   if (!exists) {
      return console.error('File does not exist');
   }
   fs.stat(fileName, function(error, stats) {
   if (error) {
     return console.error(error);
   } else if (!stats.isFile()) {
     return console.error('Not a file');
   }
   fs.readFile(fileName, 'utf8', function(error, data) {
     if (error) {
       return console.error(error);
     }
     console.log(data);
   });
  });
});
```

The book i am reading point out "**Callback Hell**" as a drawback in this design pattern. I just get started with Node.js so it's a little bit difficult to grasp the idea.

can anyone explain it better ?

Comment: If you indent your code properly, you'll see that it veers off to the right more and more for each level of callback. That in itself is bad enough.

Comment: Read https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_exists_path_callback

Comment: You can use `fs-extra` package as a promisified replacement for `fs`. Then either use promises as-is or the new `async`/`await` to resolve the callback hell. (In general. In this specific instance, yes, `fs.exists` should not be used.)

Comment: can named function resolve the issues ?

Comment: If you just name the functions, no. If you name the functions and extract them out, then you replace the indent hell with fragmented code, which can be good or not, depending on how much sense it makes to extract the function from the location it was in.

Comment: @user292174 only to a small extend they can help. You still end up with the famous **pyramid of doom**. Using promises is a much cleaner and more readable way of dealing with this anti-pattern.

Comment: OP, the edit was helpful in demonstrating what "callback hell" is, syntactically (as your original code is mis-indented). Rolling back @JeremyThille's edit was a disservice to yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you have many asynchronous operations, this will quickly lead to huge, monolithic, unreadable, untestable and unmaintainable code :

```
doSomething(
     20 lines of code
     whenItsDone(
           20 more lines of code
           whenItsDone(
                  20 morelines of code
                  whenItsDone(
                       20 more lines of code
                       whenItsDone(
                               20 more lines of code
                               whenItsDone(
                                       20 more lines of code
                                       whenItsDone(
                                              20 more lines of code
                                              Finally all done !
                                        )
                                )
                         )
                 )
        )
)
```

In order to prevent that, different methods are available. You need to break down your code into unitary functions, use Promises or libraries like Async (NodeJS), etc.